# Clean customized error message in component react Form once focus in Input field after it submitted

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

this is a react form that display individual error if user let empty any input field when click submit button as validation.

On render page, focus is on first input field before user submit it, once it is submitted empty errors are displayed and focus is lost for any input field.

Expected result is remove somehow the error once user focus on any field.

I tried regaining focus on input with function `onFocusHandler` and returned `result["estado"]`**[InputField]** in function `validField` into
`RegistrationPage.js` file

Thanks in advance for help, hits and/or solution.

[image]

`InputField.js`

```
import Form from "react-bootstrap/Form";

export default function InputField({
  name,
  label,
  type,
  placeholder,
  error,
  fieldRef,
  onFocus,
}) {
  return (
    <Form.Group controlId={name} className="InputField">
      {label && <Form.Label>{label}</Form.Label>}
      <Form.Control
        type={type || "text"}
        placeholder={placeholder}
        ref={fieldRef}
        onFocus={onFocus}
      />
      <Form.Text className="text-danger">{error}</Form.Text>
    </Form.Group>
  );
}
```

`Registration Page`

```
import { useState, useEffect, useRef } from "react";
import Form from "react-bootstrap/Form";
import Button from "react-bootstrap/Button";
import InputField from "../components/InputField";
// other imports ...

const validField = (fields) => {
// Validate input fields and return errors
  const result = { estado: {}, errores: {} };
  const usrnm = fields.username === "";
  const email = fields.email === "";
  const pass1 = fields.password === "";
  const pass2 = fields.password2 !== fields.password;

  result["estado"]["username"] = usrnm;
  result["estado"]["email"] = email;
  result["estado"]["password"] = pass1;
  result["estado"]["password2"] = pass2;

  if (usrnm) {
    result["errores"]["username"] = "Username cannot be empty";
  }
  if (email) {
    result["errores"]["email"] = "Email cannot be empty";
  }
  if (pass1) {
    result["errores"]["password"] = "Password cannot be empty";
  }
  if (pass2) {
    result["errores"]["password2"] = "Password does not match";
  }
  return result;
};

export default function RegistrationPage() {
  const [formErrors, setFormErrors] = useState({});
  const [usernameTouched, setUsernameTouched] = useState(false);

  const usernameField = useRef();
  const emailField = useRef();
  const passwordField = useRef();
  const password2Field = useRef();
  let estadoErrores = {};

  useEffect(() => {
  // initial focus and reset status to false
    usernameField.current.focus();
    setUsernameTouched(false);
  }, []);

  function onFocusHandler() {
  // Detect when user focus input after submit empty field 
    setUsernameTouched(true);
  }

  useEffect(() => {
  // pleaceholder for remove error message
    console.log(usernameTouched);
  }, [usernameTouched]);

  const onSubmit = async (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    const registerData = {
      username: usernameField.current.value.trim(),
      email: emailField.current.value.trim(),
      password: passwordField.current.value,
      password2: password2Field.current.value,
    };
    estadoErrores = validField(registerData);
    setFormErrors(estadoErrores["errores"]);

return (
    <Body>
      <h1>Register</h1>
      <Form onSubmit={onSubmit}>
        <InputField
          name="username"
          label="Username"
          error={formErrors.username}
          fieldRef={usernameField}
          onFocus={onFocusHandler}
        />
        <InputField
          name="email"
          label="Email address"
          error={formErrors.email}
          fieldRef={emailField}
        />
        <InputField
          name="password"
          label="Password"
          type="password"
          error={formErrors.password}
          fieldRef={passwordField}
        />
       <InputField
          name="password2"
          label="Password again"
          type="password"
          error={formErrors.password2}
          fieldRef={password2Field}
        />
        <Button variant="primary" type="submit">
          Register
        </Button>
      </Form>
    </Body>
  );
}
```